# What is the error in this .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using mod_rewrite, I want to look for all requested files in an `assets` directory, and otherwise fallback to `index.php` for API calls. This is my `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+\.[^/]+$ assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Asset files are determined by whether the last last url segment has a file extension, which means a dot without following slashes. I already tested the [regex at regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E.%2b%5C.%5B%5E/%5D%2b%24&input=Requests%20to%20API%0A---------------%0A/%0A/api%0A/call/to/api/%0A/call/with.dot/inside%0A%0ARequests%20to%20assets%0A------------------%0A/path/to/file.txt%0A/file.with.dots%0A/file.txt%0A) and it seems to work fine.

Unfortunately, all request result in a `500 Internal Server Error` using these rewrite rules. I know that mod_rewrite is set up correctly, since omitting the second line works as expected.

Comment: Probably it is a redirect loop. You need to first look in your error log to find out more about the 500 error, then probably exclude `index.php` from the second matching rule.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Isn't the `[L]` flag supposed to stop after a matching rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite to assets/file if file exists in assets dir
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.[^/]+)/?$ assets/$1 [L]

# otherwise rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^assets/ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. Just for my understanding, what do I need the regex in the first `RewriteRule` for? I would think that is already given by the `RewriteCond` right above. Moreover, can't I omit the second `RewriteCond`? I explicitly want to not deliver files outside the assets directory.

Comment: Actually `RewriteCond` in 2nd rule can be omitted without any problems.

Comment: Sorry missed answering your first question. `RewriteCond` in 1st rule is to ascertain that file does exist in assets directory and then regex is to capture URI in `$1`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. However, can't we capture the URI more easily after already knowing that the file exists? I though of just `.*` but that didn't work.

Comment: @danijar: Totally agree even `^(.+)$` is sufficient (I just copied the regex from question without tampering it :P)

Comment: Alright, thanks. By the way using the `-f` switch is even better because I can now handle assets not found in PHP.

Comment: Yes that's true `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is pretty handy for your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition to prevent the rewrite engine from looping:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^.+\.[^/]+$ assets/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

The rewrite engine loops until the URI stops changing, and since `.*` matches `index.php` as well, it'll continue to loop through that rule until the internal recursion limit is reached you get a 500 error.

Additionally, you can add conditions that won't reroute existing files or directories:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^.+\.[^/]+$ assets/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```